# MASM Array Permutation will only accept single digit numbers

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am creating an assembly program that will take the 10 elements entered by the user and sort them into 8, 3, 5, 9, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 7 using permutation. The program is working, however my issue is that it will not work with double digit numbers. If I enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0.. it will give me the correct output. But if I enter something like 12, 9, 54, 20, 3, 38, 72, 17, 91, 25.. it will not give me the desired output of 91, 20, 38, 25, 54, 72, 12, 3, 9, 17.. it will just give me no output at all. What is causing this?

Here is my code

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
welcome BYTE "Welcome! This program permutates an array of size 10.", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
message1 BYTE "Please enter the 10 elements of your array:", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
message2 BYTE "The permutated array is: ", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
permutation DWORD 8, 3, 5, 9, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 7
array DWORD 10 DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

MOV EDX, OFFSET welcome
call WriteString


MOV EDX, OFFSET message1
call WriteString
MOV ESI, OFFSET array
MOV ECX, 10

L1:
    call ReadInt
    MOV [ESI], EAX
    ADD ESI, TYPE array
    LOOP L1

MOV EDI, OFFSET permutation
MOV ESI, OFFSET array
MOV ECX, 10

L2:
    MOV EAX, [EDI]
    PUSH ECX
    MOV ECX, 10

    L3:
        CMP EAX, [ESI]
        JE output
        ADD ESI, TYPE array
        LOOP L3
        back:

    ADD EDI, TYPE permutation
    POP ECX
    LOOP L2



    JMP quit





    output:

        MOV EAX, [ESI]
        call WriteInt
        MOV ESI, OFFSET array
        JMP back


quit:
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You don't really sort anything What you do could be described as `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { if (find(permutation[i], array)) { print(array[i]); } }`

Comment: So you only print those values that exist both in `array` and `permutation`.

Comment: Okay, I'm not entirely understanding. My program sorts the numbers correctly but it won't sort double digit numbers? Why is this? Thanks.

Comment: For the reasons I explained in my previous comments. You should probably implement this in another language like Java or C first until you understand the algorithm, because the algorithm you've implemented in your assembly code is not correct. Once you have a working program you can begin transcribing it into assembly.

Comment: If you write your algorithm in C/C++ and are on a linux/unix/mac system then you can add the -S compile flag and it will output assembly. This can sometimes help. But like @Michael said, implement in another language like C/C++ and oddly enough both C and C++ have in a lot of cases a near 1 to 1 mapping to assembly in terms of lines of code. This doesn't always hold but it can help when translating code.